# What is wrong with my php and html code?

Tags: php, html

```
           <?php
include ("db.php");
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION["user"];


if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_dir = "pics/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));



//check if there was an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "The file couldnt be upload, please try again";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded";
    } else {

    echo "Sorry there was a error";
    }
}

    $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];

    $title = $_POST["cardname"];
    $info = $_POST["description"];
    $insta = $_POST["insta"];
    $snap = $_POST["snap"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $bg = $_POST["bg"];
    $discord = $_POST["discord"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cards WHERE code = '".$code."'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Please pick a new id, that one is already taken";
    } else {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO cards (title, user, link, code, image, description, likes, snap, insta, yt, bg, discord)
        VALUES ('$title', '$user', '$link', '$code', '$img', '$info', '0', '$snap', '$insta', '$user', '$bg', '$discord')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New card created!";
        } else {
            echo "There was an error";
        }
    }
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Personal cards for your social media or business | SocialCard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .white {
                color: white !important;
            }
        </style>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="big">Cards</h1><br>
            <?php

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM cards WHERE user = '$user'";

        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

        if($result3->num_rows > 0) {
            //output cards
            while($row  = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>   

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-top">
                            <img alt="" src="pics/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>



            <br>


            <?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?>
<hr>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h4>Card Name:</h4>
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="cardname">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Profile Image:</h4>
        <input type="file" name="img">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Short info:</h4>
        <input type="text" name="description">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Instagram link:</h4>
        <br>

        <input type="text" name="insta">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Snapchat link:</h4>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="snap">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Discord Tag:</h4>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="discord">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Background Color:</h4>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="bg" placeholder="#hexcode">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Unique Id:</h4>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Create One :), remember it" name="code" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create Card</button>
        <p>To get to your card go to: social-card.pw/view.php?code=youruniqueid</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card bg-dark">
            <div class="card-content white">
                <h1 class="text-center font1">Purchase Premium</h1>
                <p class="text-center">Nothing here yet</p>
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p258030.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=258030_546328_0&type=footer&size=37'></script>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>



























</html>
```

This is my current php and html code, I must of made a small error because I everytime I go to view it the only thing that shows on my screen is the jumbotron at the top with the test "card" inside it, please help me! I'm sure its just a small error that I cant find out the answer to.

Im assuming its the php code, if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: You would probably benefit from changing your title, it's a bit too generic.

Comment: Are we supposed to debug your code? Why don't you learn to debug it? start by enabling display errors, so you can tell us something more than "why is this not working" ? Give us a specific error, not  bunch of code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your query is actually retrieving the cards, the display isn't fetching the image from the returned result...

```
   while($row  = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>   
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img-top">
                    <img alt="" src="pics/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Using `$img` for the image isn't using the data from `$row`.

You should have something like...

```
echo $row['image'];
```

I'm also unsure if there is an extra `</div>` in the loop, you may need to move the last `</div>` outside the loop, but check this with the generated source.

Comment: Hey, it still doesnt display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `session_start()` at the first line of page, i.e.:

```
session_start();
include ("db.php");
```

---

`session_start();` must be started **before** any other line or operation.

```
   <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="big">Cards</h1><br>
            <?php

    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM cards WHERE user = '$user'";

    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

    if($result3->num_rows > 0) {
        //output cards
        while($row  = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>   

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img-top">
                        <img alt="" src="pics/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Check all closing `div`

Comment: Thankyou for the tip, however that didnt change the problem and it really doesnt have an effect at all.

Comment: check your closing div.